# I can't get my rig to attach to my model

Tags: rigging

I have cleaned up the model using the clean up tools, but every time I try to parent - armature deform with automatic weights my model grows a thousand times its size and they aren't connected.

this is a copy of the file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NiiyVZrLf8ldHE7WCG9vIuKdr6NhaAf1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please use the site dedicated to BSE to upload file: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model is parented to an empty which is scaled down:

[image]

In consequence, when parenting to the armature, the object looses the empty as parent and get back its original size.

Before parenting to the armature, select the model and use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to clear parent then choose *"keep transforms"*.

Finally, select both armature and model, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to apply scale.

Then parent the model to the armature.

Comment: Super helpful thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the scale to the armature (metarig) and the mesh before you parent them. Select them, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, `apply scale`.

Comment: Thankyou, I thought I tried this and it didn't work for me the first time. I will try it again. I did find that if I move the file out of the SketchUp collection it worked as well.